# checkbox in table with tableviewer in eclipse rcp

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, rcp

I'd like to add a checkbox to a column. I am using a tableViewer. The user shouldn't be able to edit the checkbox.

Google wasn't helpful so far, so I came here.

my labelprovider looks like this:

```
    this.tableViewer2 = new TableViewer(table1);
    this.tableViewer2.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    this.tableViewer2.setLabelProvider(new ITableLabelProvider() {


        @Override
        public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {

            Platz p = (Platz) element;
            switch (columnIndex) {

            case 0:
                return p.getReihe().getReihenfolge().toString();
            case 1:
                return p.getNummer().toString();
            case 2:
                return p.getKategorie().getPreisstd().toString();

            }
            return null;
        }

    });
```

I'd like to add a fourth column with a checkbox but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ITableLableProvider has a method getColumnImage().

Just override it and return an image of the checkbox.

```
   this.tableViewer2 = new TableViewer(table1);
   this.tableViewer2.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
   this.tableViewer2.setLabelProvider(new ITableLabelProvider() {

    @Override
    public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex) {
         //do magic here and return an image :)
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {

        Platz p = (Platz) element;
        switch (columnIndex) {

        case 0:
            return p.getReihe().getReihenfolge().toString();
        case 1:
            return p.getNummer().toString();
        case 2:
            return p.getKategorie().getPreisstd().toString();

        }
        return null;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking too complicated. I wanted to add a real checkbox, but the image method works well and is much easier.